# Is there a point to collecting coins in Super Mario 3D Land?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

Assuming one has plenty of extra lives, is there any value, in general, to collecting coins in Super Mario 3D Land?

If like [in Super Mario Galaxy 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29969/is-there-a-point-to-collecting-coins-in-super-mario-galaxy-2) there is a use for coins but only those collected in a specific level, then please don't name the level, just say that there are such levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** The only purpose of regular coins is to get extra lives.